# Fetch Office365 email from the email server in PHP

Tags: php, email, office365

I am unable to fetch the emails from Office 365 mailbox using IMAP.

This used to work perfectly fine when we used to fetch the same from Gmail while now it is getting the following error:

Can't connect to 'hostname',port_number.

I got hostname by following this link => https://support.knowbe4.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006834408-How-To-Find-Your-Office-365-Host-Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try use the /authuser method.

```
    imap_open("{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/authuser=user@maindomain.com}", "user@maindomain.com", "password");
```

Comment: Thanks @zhir for your reply. Although "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX" this hostname worked for me. :)

Comment: I've tried: 
 imap_open('{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/authuser=information-systems-etl@expedient.com}', 'username', 'password')

But am getting a generic error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Notice: Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after AUTHENTICATE failed. (errflg=1) in Unknown:0